# Cant install All pods. : Failed to connect to dl.inmobi.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I take a clone of project and run `pod install` command but it's can't install all pods and endup with following error ...

[image]

i tried reinstall the pods but it's does't work ... re installing the cocoapods also does't work ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with InMobiSDK and using VPN helped me.